# VMWare Workstation on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vmware-workstation

I followed the steps this link and it was good. However when I install the vmware it self, I' having this error

[image]

```
j-l0@Liyan-PC:~/Downloads/VMware Workstation 12 Pro v12.5.0 build 4352439 Final x64$ sudo ./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe
./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe: 1: ./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe: MZ����@���: not found
./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe: 2: ./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe: $�喗��������������: not found
./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe: 2: ./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe: �������k��������ę���H�n�������m�ׄ����{Ĥ�����: not found
./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe: 2: ./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe: đ����c������b������e�����Rich����PELF{�W�
                                                              : not found
./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe: 3: ./VMware-workstation-full-12.5.0-4352439.exe: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Comment: Looks like this is unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: what do you mean mike?

Comment: Just what I said. The question is about some Windows executable errors, which is not about Ubuntu. It's also unclear what is being done, and what link you've followed.

Comment: You can't run Windows programs on Linux... you'll need to download the Linux version

Comment: do you have a program for ubuntu for the virtualization?

Comment: Please help if you may have a little information

Comment: Try the linux download from [vmware.com](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/12_0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the Linux version of VMware. [Here's the link](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=WKST-1256-LX&productId=524&rPId=16253).

---

A free alternative would be [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox), which you can install by doing:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Comment: @JLoc - If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by ticking the little check mark in the upper left :)

Comment: @ Android Dev  why does my login screen show another group liberty?? quemo? how do i add that

Comment: @JLoc - I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: after I install the virtual manager and I restart my pc before I logon to my screen I create another account which librvirt quemo how will I add that to my account

Comment: - The 'libvirt-bin' package is installed
 - The 'libvirtd' daemon has been started
 - You are member of the 'libvirtd' group

Comment: Unable to connect to libvirt.
Verify that:
 - The 'libvirt-bin' package is installed
 - The 'libvirtd' daemon has been started
 - You are member of the 'libvirtd' group